# Problems re formatting a date value in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am having major problems re formatting a date value to put it back into the database. When the user selects the date using the jquery date picker it displays it in a nice easy to read way, I am then trying to re format it to put it into the mysql database.

If I echo the posted value of $weddingdate I get the following format back :

Thursday, 14 March, 2013

So......I am taking that and reformatting it using the following :

```
if (isset($_POST['weddingdate'])) {$weddingdate = $_POST['weddingdate'];}else {$weddingdate = '';}

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("D F d, Y", $weddingdate);
$processedweddingdate = $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

The thing is if I echo $date I get nothing at all ?, if I then uncomment the second line I get Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\easyphp\www\twinfocus\submiteditcalendaritem.php on line 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert the date to string with `strtotime` and use `date` to change the format...

try this

```
<?php
$weddingdate=$_POST['weddingdate'];
$finaldate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($weddingdate));
echo $finaldate;
```

Comment: Thanks !, that has sorted it out :-)